# How to Limit the Number of Post Items Shown In a Feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Quick question, I believe this can be easily answered. I have this line of code in my PagesController which shows all posts relative to a user:

```
@microfeed_items = Micropost.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

Is there something I can add to this line of code so that say, only the 5 most recent posts are shown?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have a created_at attribute in your model for calling `order`, if not, you could order by ID descending, assuming they're assigned incrementally. This should do it for you:

```
@microfeed_items = Micropost.where(:user_id => current_user.id).limit(5).order("created_at DESC")
```

Have a look at the Rails guide on ActiveRecord queries for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset

Comment: Wouldn't he need an order applied to this if he wanted the most recent posts?

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup the relationship between `User` and `Micropost` correctly, you should be able to use `current_user.microposts`. Then you can use the `last` method to return the last 5 posts:

```
@microfeed_items = current_user.microposts.last(5)
```